# How to create a spark DataFrame from sequenceFile

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am working with spark 1.5. I want to create a `dataframe` from files in HDFS. The HDFS files contain `json` data with a large number of fields in sequence input file format.

Is there a way to do this elegantly in java? I don't know the structure/fields of json in advance.

I am able to take input from sequence file as RDD as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<LongWritable,BytesWritable> inputRDD = jsc.sequenceFile("s3n://key_id:secret_key@file/path", LongWritable.class, BytesWritable.class);
JavaRDD<String> events = inputRDD.map(
    new Function<Tuple2<LongWritable,BytesWritable>, String>() {
        public String call(Tuple2<LongWritable,BytesWritable> tuple) {
            return Text.decode(tuple._2.getBytes());
        }
    }
);
```

How can I create a data frame from this RDD?

Comment: Data frames require some sort of structure/schema defined when you convert an RDD to data frame. Are you able to explore the data a bit and determine the JSON structure? Are you able to talk to your data source provider and agree on a common schema?

Comment: Can you not simply call `sqlContext.createDataFrame(events)`? You do not have to actually define a schema, columns will simply be named C0, C1 etc. if you do not.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt: Thanks for your post. Yes, I figured that out eventually. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following for json data in my sequence files:

```
    JavaRDD<String> events = inputRDD.map(
    new Function<Tuple2<LongWritable,BytesWritable>, String>() {
        public String call(Tuple2<LongWritable,BytesWritable> tuple) throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            String valueAsString = new String(tuple._2.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(valueAsString);
            JSONObject payload = new JSONObject(data.getString("payload"));
            String atlas_ts = "";
            return payload.toString();
        }
    }
    );
```